# Excel VBA - Combine and duplicate rows/columns

Tags: excel, vba

Can anyone help or guide me on how I can create a macro in Excel that will create new rows from certain columns while duplicating all other surrounding values?

For example, I need to turn this:

```
A 1 2 3 4 B
C 5 6 7 8 D
```

Into this:

```
A 1 B
A 2 B
A 3 B
A 4 B
C 5 D
C 6 D
C 7 D
C 8 D
```

I've found a way to combine the columns using the below macro:

```
Sub SingleColumn()
Dim CurSh As Worksheet, NewSh As Worksheet, Rng As Range, Col As Long

Set CurSh = ActiveSheet
Set NewSh = Sheets.Add
CurSh.Activate
Set Rng = Application.Intersect(Selection, CurSh.UsedRange)

For Col = 1 To Selection.Columns.Count
    Rng.Range(Cells(1, Col), Cells(Rng.Rows.Count, Col)).Copy NewSh.Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
Next Col
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the code like that:

```
Sub SingleColumn()
    Dim CurSh As Worksheet, NewSh As Worksheet, Rng As Range, Col As Long, Row As Long

    Set CurSh = ActiveSheet
    Set NewSh = Sheets.Add
    CurSh.Activate
    Set Rng = Application.Intersect(Selection, CurSh.UsedRange)

    For Row = 1 To Selection.Rows.Count
        For Col = 1 To Selection.Columns.Count
            Rng.Range(Cells(Row, Col).Address).Copy NewSh.Range("A1").Offset(Col - 1, Row - 1)
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

For me you have a little bit complicated the macro ...